# Google Contacts API: Temporary internal error, when uploading contact photos in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, api, google-contacts-api, http-status-code-500

I need to change the contact photo for a large number of contacts, using the python client for the Google Contacts API 3.0

```
gdata==2.0.18
```

The code I'm running is:

```
client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source=MY_APP_NAME)
GDClientAuth(client, MY_AUTH)

def _get_valid_contact(contact_id):
    contact = client.GetContact(contact_id)
    if contact.GetPhotoLink() is None:
        # Generate a proper photo link for this contact
        link = gdata.contacts.data.ContactLink()
        link.etag = '*'
        link.href = generate_photo_url(contact)
        link.rel = 'http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo'
        link.type = 'image/*'
        contact.link.append(link)
    return contact

def upload_photo(contact_id, image_path, image_type, image_size):
    contact = _get_valid_contact(contact_id)
    try:
        client.ChangePhoto(media=image_path,
                           contact_entry_or_url=contact,
                           content_type=image_type,
                           content_length=image_size)
    except gdata.client.RequestError as req:
        if req.status == 412:
            #handle etag mismatches, etc...
            pass
```

Given a list of valid Google contact ids, if I run the **upload_photo** method sequentially for each of them, everything goes smoothly, and all the contacts get their photo changed:

```
for contact_id in CONTACT_ID_LIST:
    upload_photo(contact_id, '/path/to/image', 'image/png', 1234)
```

However, if I try to upload the photos in parallel (using at least 4 threads), **some of them** shall randomly fail with **500, A temporary internal problem has occurred. Try again later** as a response to the client.ChangePhoto call. I can retry these photos later, though, and they finally get updated:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4)
for contact_id in CONTACT_ID_LIST:
    pool.apply_async(func=upload_photo,
                     args=(contact_id,'/path/to/image', 'image/png', 1234))
```

The more threads I use, the more frequently the error happens.

The only similar issue I could find is http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2507, and it was solved some time ago.
The issue I'm facing now might be different, as it happens randomly, and only when running the updates in parallel. So there are chances there might be a race condition at some point at the Google Contacts API end.

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://github.com/agilecrm/rest-api/issues/15), you might get 500 server error for wrong format of input or else server was not able to load data properly. You may also check these links: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2561 and https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=42828.